# Добавить друзей ASP.NET Core EF

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

3 час сижу и не знаю где промахнулся, в общем есть таблица в бд с юзерами, есть таблица друзей, в ней 2 поля - юзерИД и френдИД, сам функционал работает отлично, жму добавить друга, все идет как надо, в первое поле записывается непосредственно авторизованный пользователь, во второе айдишник добавляемого. Проблема в другом, когда я вывожу юзера и его друзей, в списке друзей прописываются айдишники его друзей, но все остальные параметры такие как юзерНейм, ластНейм итп устанавливаются с авторизованного пользователя... надеюсь объяснил доступно, погоним в код:

И так вот сам юзер:

```
public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            UserFriends = new List<Friends>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<Friends> UserFriends { get; set; }
    }
```

фреднс:

```
public class Friends
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int FriendId { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }



    }
```

параметры в контексте дб:

```
public class DBUserContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DBUserContext()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.FriendId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.User)
                .WithMany(s => s.UserFriends)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.FriendId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.User)
                .WithMany(c => c.UserFriends)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.UserId);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=SocNW;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
```

ну и метод добавления я думаю смысла писать нет, ведь он работает и все добавляется на свои места как положено, перейдем к проблеме. Для того, чтобы браузер не ругался на списки в списках (в прошлом проекте я с этим намучался, и тут сразу сделал выводы) я специально создал 2 модели представления UserViewModel и UserFriendsViewModel. 
вот код UserViewModel :

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<UserFriendsViewModel> Friends { get; set; }
    }
```

вот UserFriendsViewModel:

```
public class UserFriendsViewModel
    {

        public UserFriendsViewModel(Friends friends)
        {
            UserId = friends.UserId;
            FriendId = friends.FriendId;            
            UserName = friends.User.UserName;
            Password = friends.User.Password;
            LastName = friends.User.LastName;
            Id = friends.FriendId;
        }       
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int FriendId { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

дальше идем к методу, который непосредственно и предоставляет мне нужного пользователя и его друзей:

```
[HttpGet, Route("getidenti"), Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            List<UserViewModel> user = db.Users.Include(x => x.UserFriends).ThenInclude(x => x.User).ToList().Select(c => new UserViewModel
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                UserName = c.UserName,
                Password = c.Password,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                Friends = c.UserFriends.Select(x => new UserFriendsViewModel(x)).ToList()
            }).ToList();
            UserViewModel userdb = user.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);


            return Ok(userdb);          
        }
```

Допустим у нас таблица френдс содержет следующие поля
userId friendId
1      2
1      3
1      5
итд.
в итоге прохожусь точкой останова и вижу что в `return Ok(userdb);` userdb.Friends содержит:
userId - 1, friendId - 2, UserName - имя принадлежащее пользователя с айдишником userId, а не friendId. Надеюсь понятно описал проблему, подскажите где я споткнулся плиз, чувствую что в какой то мелочи ошибся, а в какой не могу понять;(
П.С. во всем этом я использовал связь многие ко многим (many to many), это ведь приемлемо?

Comment: в модели Friends у тебя навигационное свойство есть только на текущего юзера, а на самого друга нет. Добавь FK и навигационное свойство и доставай его.
В контексте у тебя неправильно настроены FK. Ты мапишь Friends и User самого на себя (второй FK, где используешь UserId). И еще мапишь друга, снова на себя (первый FK, где используешь User -> FriendId).

Comment: @SultanovShamil не могу уложить в голове как добавить навигационное свойство на друга, ведь друг тоже юзер..можете подсказать плс?. по поводу контекста перерыл кучу вариантов, рабочим оказался только тот, который сейчас, но значит это произошло из-за первой проблемы, которую вы описали...

Comment: @SultanovShamil проблема в том, что я уже сталкивался с тем, когда у меня 2 типа сущностей, и мне надо один тип добавить ко второму и наоборот, но тут ведь только 1 тип сущности, это Юзер, а значит что и сам пользователь и все его друзья находятся в одной таблице бд, и как сделать навигационное свойство на тот же самый класс, только чтобы он брал имена и фамилии подпадающие под айди друга... этого не могу понять т.к. не сталкивался еще...

Comment: добавь навигационное свойство с тем же типом:
public User Friend {get; set;}
и в контексте укажи связь User.Friend -> Friend.FriendId

Comment: @SultanovShamil Добавил в модель Friends - public User Friend { get; set; }, теперь там 4 поля, юзерИД, френдИД, public User User , public User Friend. А вот с контекстом все никак не получается разобраться, плис в ответе мб напишете как контекст составить, я уже перепробовал все что можно, не могу понять принцип, как указать правильно в такой ситуации, заранее огромно признателен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал как показано ниже, и все заработало как надо

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.FriendId });           

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.User)
                .WithMany(c => c.UserFriends)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.FriendId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Friends>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.Friend)
                .WithMany(s => s.WhoAddMe)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.FriendId);
```